# Google recaptcha when posting to different server

Tags: recaptcha

I have a form with recaptcha V2:

https://www.fisherwallace.com/pages/do-you-qualify-to-use-the-device

It posts to a different server and then redirects back to a different page on the server with the recaptcha form.

Recaptcha site says: "We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions." I assume it's due to posting to the different server.

NOTE: You'll see I have a clumsy workaround at the moment to address the fact that the recaptcha does not challenge automatically. Without the workaround, the recaptcha is there but nothing happens on submit.

I found some sample PHP code for the server side...

```
$email;$comment;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['email'])){
          $email=$_POST['email'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
          $comment=$_POST['comment'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
        $secretKey = "Put your secret key here";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        // post request to server
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secretKey) .  '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        // should return JSON with success as true
        if($responseKeys["success"]) {
                echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment</h2>';
        } else {
                echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
        }
```

Clearly lots of this code is moot since the user does not actually load the POST server page.

But will this part get the callback recaptcha needs?

```
$secretKey = "Put your secret key here";
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            // post request to server
            $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secretKey) .  '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
            $response = file_get_contents($url);
            $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
            // should return JSON with success as true
```

If the IP is a mismatch, can i hard code it using the IP from the originating server?

Answer (score 0):

1. IP is optional
2. You need to do file_get_contents 'method'  => 'POST' for siteverify

Comment: Can you explain "You need to do file_get_contents 'method' => 'POST' for siteverify"? Are you saying the "siteverify" in the $url has to be replaced by [file_get_contents 'method' => 'POST' ]?

Comment: google recaptcha siteverify accept POST method only, file_get_contents is using GET by default unless you change the method,  Example #1 Fetch a page and send POST data https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php